# Quitting driver in Selenium webdriver Exception

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to handle exceptions for a code i'm writing to scrape a site, problem is i'm not able to close/quit the driver whenever the exception is raised and instead the page stays open, i'm expecting the print to show something like `"driver: None couldn't open offer page to scrape, trying to reinitialize browser"` and the webpage to be closed.

Instead it always prints the same driver, and the page doesn't close: `driver: <selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver (session="00fcf9041385afda7e8d7df73aba083e")> couldn't open offer page to scrape, trying to reinitialize browser`

```
    for i in range(5):
        time.sleep(random.randint(2, 5))
        try:
            driver.get(url_offer)
            break
        except Exception:
            driver.quit()
            print("driver: "+str(driver)+" couldn't open offer page to scrape, trying to reinitialize browser")
            driver = self.start_driver()
            pass
```

How do i correctly handle exceptions like this? Thanks.

Comment: why would you want to close the page or re-start the driver?  Just continue...   If you really want to re-start the driver, do as you've done there.. use driver.quit()... but you'll want a sleep of a few seconds (I've found 5 secs is good)... things will take a little time to shutdown and cleanup (driver and browser)  Then initialize the new driver.  Otherwise you risk some odd session quirks.

Comment: if you start a new driver without quitting the previous session, the browser tab of the previous version stays open, i'll try to sleep for 5 secs and see if it works like this.

Comment: adding a sleep doesn't change much, the session ID stays the same and it looks like it has basically no effect, i can't understand why i'm not able to quit the current session

Comment: that is odd... maybe a scope issue... hard to tell.  After quit() the driver should be null.